# Background color of Div based on current date n time

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css

```
<div class="timeRow">
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 12:00:00 PM">&nbsp;</a> </div>
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 12:15:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 12:30:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 12:45:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 01:00:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
.
.
.
.
.
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 07:00:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 07:15:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 07:30:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 07:45:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
    <div class="timeRowCell>
        <a title="1/02/2014 08::00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
</div>
```

Can I give background color for the four divs based on the current date and hour? Like if it is 01/02/2014 01:15pm, I want to change background color of below four divs

```
<div class="timeRowCell>
    <a title="1/02/2014 01:00:00 PM">&nbsp;</a> </div>
<div class="timeRowCell>
    <a title="1/02/2014 01:15:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
<div class="timeRowCell>
    <a title="1/02/2014 01:30:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
<div class="timeRowCell>
    <a title="1/02/2014 01:45:00 PM">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: Just want to change the background color of those Divs containing ancor tags of the Time 1/02/2014 01:00:00 PM to 1/02/2014 01:45:00 PM to Yellow color. I hope I made sense. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: So do you mean you want to change the background if the current hour and title hour are the same? This would be much easier if you use 24hr time.

Comment: Can you change you title output date format to unixtimestamp?

Comment: Can I please know how is it possible with 24hr format? Maybe is it possible in javascript to first convert  the anchor Title time to 24hr format?

Comment: It just makes matching much easier. The ECMAScript Date object returns hours 0-24, so to match the above requires conversion of am/pm to 24 hr time or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following. It can match only on the time, or time and date if you wish:

```
function doBackground() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.timeRowCell a');
  var now = new Date();
  var currentHour = now.getHours();
  var ampm = currentHour < 12? 'am' : 'pm';

  // To match on time only, use this line
  var re = new RegExp((currentHour%12 || 12) + ':\\d\\d:\\d\\d ' + ampm, 'i');

  // To match on date also, use these lines
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  var re = new RegExp(now.getDate() + '\\/' + z(now.getMonth()+1) +
                      '\\/' + now.getFullYear() +
                      ' ' + (currentHour%12 || 12) +
                      ':\\d\\d:\\d\\d ' + ampm, 'i'
            ); 

  // Loop over elements looking for matches to change the background of
  for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (re.test(elements[i].title)) {
      elements[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  }
}
```

It creates a single Date object and regular expression, and only loops over anchors that match the selection criteria so should be pretty fast. Note that it requires support for querySelectorAll, so IE 8 and above (or any reasonably modern browser).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');  // get All anchors
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var dateInAnchor = new Date(anchors[i].title);   //anchor's title as date
        if(dateInAnchor >= new Date("1/02/2014 01:00:00 PM") && dateInAnchor <= new Date("1/02/2014 01:45:00 PM")){  //when condition matches
            var parentDiv = anchors[i].parentElement;  
            parentDiv.style.background = "yellow";    //change background of parent div
        }
    };
```

Comment: ***Please*** don't parse dates using the Date constructor. It's unreliable and produces different results in different browers (is 1/02/2014 1 February or 2 January?). Manually parse the string (2 lines of code). Also, this needlessly creates 2 Date objects on each itereation.